# How to execute python script by terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, python

I wanted to learn Python, I installed some software. I created a little execution files and none of them will execute. So I've checked my terminal and type basic things like `Is`, `cd` etc. None of them work

```
:Users me$ cd
:~ me$ cd
:~ me$ cd /
:/ me$ Is
-bash: Is: command not found
:/ me$ cd ~
:~ me$ cd desktop
:desktop me$
```

If I type `echo $PATH`, here the result:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I read many things about how to fix it but I don't understand. For example:

- I don't know how to find the **User Folder**
- I don't know how to get to the **bash.profile**

Bear in mind that I am very new to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to list all files/folders in a directory, you should type `ls` not `Is`. It is L, not i.

To learn python, you won't need to reach `~/.bash_profile` unless you need to change versions. Just use `which python` or  `python --version` and use the syntax for the version that appears. Or use online compilers for quick testing.

Suppose you have your file `learn.py` at Desktop, you type `cd ~/Desktop`, type `ls` to confirm, and then to run the file as a script, type `python learn.py`. To enter python console, type `python` and use it.

Wherever your file is, you could type `cd` in Terminal, then drag your file into Terminal window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Terminal will resolve the path for you.

For further help, refer to Stack Overflow.  :)

If you want to see bash profile, open Finder, type <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to reveal hidden files and then <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and type `~/.bash_profile` in "Go To". But **don't** edit it unless required.

Comment: If location of file is not desktop, u can type `cd` and then drag folder into terminal window and type `ENTER`. That will bring you there.

Comment: @MarcoM.vonHagen Might need to point out that you shouldn't actually type ENTER, but rather press the 'Enter' key.

Comment: @GlenYates You are absolut right. `<kbd>Enter</kbd>` will result in `Enter`-key . But not in comments ;-(

Answer (score 2):

if python is installed already just go to terminal, go to correct directory and type "python filename.py"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please note the author of the question is "very new" to Terminal; they probably don't know what you mean by "go to correct directory".

Comment: In case of 'very new' I would suggest to learn `bash shell` before python. That knowledge will be helpful when digging into `python` later on.

Comment: "if python is installed already " - When won't it be installed?

Comment: @MarcoM.vonHagen No need for shell - you can do anything in python that shell can do - and it is a more sane syntax. Especially if you are used to GUI